# Are these 2 events independent?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

We draw 4 cards from a standard 52-card deck.

$A$ is the event that we draw 4 different color cards.

$B$ is the event that we draw at most 3 aces.

I have calculated $P(A)$ and $P(B)$, and I know that they are independent if $P(A|B)P(B)=P(A)P(B)$, but I don't know how to calculate $P(A|B)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it's easier to compute $P(A\cap B)$ since $P(A|B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Also, please edit the question. It should be ``$A$ is the event .. $B$ is the event ...''

Comment: I'm sorry, edited.

Comment: Alright, now you have to calculate the probability of the event $C$: the $4$ cards are of different color and at least $3$ of them are aces, and then tell us whether $P(C)=P(A)P(B)$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These events are not independent. Here is a trick that allows us to see that without computing anything.

Let $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$ denote the complement of events $A$ and $B$, respectively. It is not too hard to see that $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$ are independent. (Prove it!)

But $\bar{A}$ is the event that we draw 3 colors or less, and $\bar{B}$ is the event that we draw 4 aces. Clearly $P( \bar{A} \cap \bar{B}) = 0$, where the probability of each individual event is positive.

Comment: That's clever. I think cleverer than what his textbook (or teacher) expects ...